# how to use the extension RealURL

Tags: typo3, realurl

I wanted to use the extension RealURL in my website,I installed it in the extensions, and this is my configuration file:

```
    <?php
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'] = array ( 
    '_DEFAULT' => array (
        'init' => array (
            'enableCHashCache' => '1',
            'appendMissingSlash' => 'ifNotFile',
            'enableUrlDecodeCache' => '1',
            'enableUrlEncodeCache' => '1',
            'emptyUrlReturnValue' => '/',
        ),
        'redirects' => array (
//          'de/aerzte.html' => '/?id=51&L=3',
        'support.html' => 'go/support-active'
        ),
        'preVars' => array (
            '0' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'no_cache',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'nc' => '1',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass'
            ),
            '1' => array (
                'GETvar' => 'L',
                'valueMap' => array (
                    'de' => '3',
                    'en' => '0',
                    'fr' => '6',
//                    '_DEFAULT' => '0',
                ),
                'noMatch' => 'bypass',
            ),            
        ),
        'pagePath' => array (
            'type' => 'user',
            'userFunc' => 'EXT:realurl/class.tx_realurl_advanced.php:&tx_realurl_advanced->main',
            'spaceCharacter' => '-',
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'expireDays' => '7',
            'rootpage_id' => 3,
        ),
        'fixedPostVars' => array (
        ),
        'postVarSets' => array (

            '_DEFAULT' => array (

        // EXT:news start
        'news' => array(
                array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
                ),
                array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
                ),
                array(
                        'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
                        'lookUpTable' => array(
                                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                                'id_field' => 'uid',
                                'alias_field' => 'title',
                                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                                'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
                                        'strtolower' => 1,
                                        'spaceCharacter' => '-',
                                ),
                                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                                'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                                'autoUpdate' => 1,
                                'expireDays' => 180,
                        ),
                ),
        ),
        // EXT:news end                


            ),
        ),
        'fileName' => array (
//
// if you don't want .html-URLs set the following to "false" (e.g. 'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => false,)
// then you get http://www.yourdomain.com/imprint/ instead of http://www.yourdomain.com/imprint.html
//
            'defaultToHTMLsuffixOnPrev' => false,
            'index' => array (
                'rss.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '100',
                    ),
                ),
                'rss091.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '101',
                    ),
                ),
                'rdf.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '102',
                    ),
                ),
                'atom.xml' => array (
                    'keyValues' => array (
                        'type' => '103',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),

); 


$domains = array(
    '_DEFAULT' => '3',
);
foreach ($domains as $domain=>$pid) {
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'][$domain] = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['_DEFAULT'];
    $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl'][$domain]['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = $pid;
}
//$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTCONF']['realurl']['www.****.com']['pagePath']['rootpage_id'] = 3;
?>
```

I excluded the pages i don't want in the url, and i deleted all the entries, i noticed the urls were changed, but the pages are not openeing anymore.
I flushed the three caches.
Thank you in advance.
edit: this was my url
https://www.***.com/en/blog/blog/article/***
i went to the first blog and exluded it from speaking url
and the second one i set it to override the whole page path
and in article i excluded it also from speaking URL
then i went to articles entries and deleted all of them
then this link worked fine:
https://www.***.com/en/blog/article/***
but this not:
https://www.***.com/en/blog
I got this in the extension in both blog pages :
URL conflict detected: 'en/blog/' is also used on page(s): 865 (/Home/Blog)
URL conflict detected: 'de/blog/' is also used on page(s): 722 (/Home/Blog/Blog)

Comment: Please edit (format) your post to make it more readable.

Comment: If you exclude the first /blog/ and /article/ fromt the speaking url, then (lang)/blog is the same as (lang)/blog/blog/article. That's why you get the conflict. Actually the error message already says it all.

Comment: so please what should i do? i only want /blog to work, and currently it's not working

Comment: Which (mapped) URL should the page /en/blog have? Which URL should the page /en/blog/blog/article have?

Answer (score 0):

For use TYPO3 `RealURL` extension you need to use below configuration.

add below typoscript in setup.ts.

```
config.simulateStaticDocuments = 0
config.tx_realurl_enable = 1
```

If `.htaccess` file not present in your root directory then add it.

check your apache configuration and if `mod_rewrite` is not enable then enable it.

Enable `mod_rewrite`  use below command for linux.

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Use Below realURL configuration.

```
'fixedPostVars' => array(
    'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
        array(
          'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
          'valueMap' => array(
            'detail' => '',
          ),
          'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ),
        array(
          'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
          'valueMap' => array(
            'News' => '',
          ),
          'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ),
        array(
          'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
          'lookUpTable' => array(
            'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
            'id_field' => 'uid',
            'alias_field' => 'title',
            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
            'useUniqueCache_conf' => array(
              'strtolower' => 1,
              'spaceCharacter' => '-'
            ),
            'languageGetVar' => 'L',
            'languageExceptionUids' => '',
            'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
            'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
            'expireDays' => 180,
          )
        )
    ),
    'blog-page-id' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
),
```

Comment: i have this in my setup.ts : skipControllerAndAction = 1, do i have to add those other two lines also ? 
I have the htaccess file, and the rewrite is one.
please see the edit i have just made i explained my problem more

Comment: Maybe i shoud change skipControllerAndAction =1 before begining with the process, it was set to 0. i will try

Comment: I just update my answers. PLease add this configuration

Comment: I already have this configuration, exept this line 'newsDetailConfiguration' , what is used for?

Comment: Then remove all URLData cache in BE. click on realURl modules -> root page. and flush all the data.